# ReactNative Fusionchart license configuration not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fusioncharts, license-key

I try to configure the license of Fusionchart in ReactNative as in this URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fusioncharts#license-configuration.

But still, it shows the watermark which should not be visible. Is there anything I missed?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import ReactNativeFusionCharts from 'react-native-fusioncharts';


global.licenseConfig = {
    key: "license-key",
    creditLabel: false // true/false to show/hide watermark respectively
};

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //STEP 2 - Chart Data
        const chartData = [
            { label: 'Venezuela', value: '250' },
            { label: 'Saudi', value: '260' },
            { label: 'Canada', value: '180' },
            { label: 'Iran', value: '140' },
            { label: 'Russia', value: '115' },
            { label: 'UAE', value: '100' },
            { label: 'US', value: '30' },
            { label: 'China', value: '30' },
        ];
        //STEP 3 - Chart Configurations
        const chartConfig = {
            type: 'column2d',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: {
                chart: {
                    caption: 'Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]',
                    subCaption: 'In MMbbl = One Million barrels',
                    xAxisName: 'Country',
                    yAxisName: 'Reserves (MMbbl)',
                    numberSuffix: 'K',
                    theme: 'fusion',
                    exportEnabled: 1, // to enable the export chart functionality
                },
                data: chartData,
            },
        };
        const events = {
            // Add your events method here:
            // Event name should be in small letters.
            dataPlotClick: (ev, props) => {
                console.log('dataPlotClick');
            },
            dataLabelClick: (ev, props) => {
                console.log('dataLabelClick');
            },
        };
        this.state = {
            chartConfig,
            events
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>FusionCharts Integration with React Native</Text>
                <View style={styles.chartContainer}>
                    <ReactNativeFusionCharts chartConfig={this.state.chartConfig} events={this.state.events} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 50,
        height: 500,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    chartContainer: {
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 1,
        height: 500,
    },
});

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeFusionCharts', () => App);
```

I also add the below code in the root component but not worked.

```
global.licenseConfig = {
    key: "license-key",
    creditLabel: false // true/false to show/hide watermark respectively
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Hope this will be helpful to someone.

Issue is latest react-native-fusionchart 5.0.0 is not updated with fusionchart 3.17.0. You may need to manually copy the fusionchart content to react-native-fusionchart.

Copy the `node_module/fusionchart` content into `node_modules/react-native-fusioncharts/src/modules/fusionchart` folder and run below script.

```
find fusioncharts -name "*.js" -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.js}.fcscript"' {} \;
```

Then the watermark vanishes as expected. These steps are configured in the gulp script but somehow it seems to be not working.

Hope this issue will be fixed soon.